# Grails GORM unique constraint on a List of BigDecimal

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-orm

I've got a class:

```
class Test {
    List<BigDecimal> values

    static constraints = {
    values(unique: true)
  }
}
```

However,

```
void testUniqueness() {
  List valList = [
   new BigDecimal(1),
   new BigDecimal(1)
  ]
  def testInstance = new Test(values: valList)
  mockForConstraintsTests(Test, [testInstance])
  assertFalse "Validation should fail for non-unique values", testInstance.validate()
}
```

This assert fails, because .validate() is true!

I want a list of BigDecimal's which is unique to each instance of the Test object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how it works. If you think about something simpler, e.g. "String username", the uniqueness check creates a unique index in the database on that column. So two users cannot have the same username/login/etc.

But you're asking for the contents of a List to be unique. The constraint (if it made sense) would compare two Lists and ensure that no two `Test` instances' `values` lists are the same. For example [1, 3, 5] <-> [1, 3] would be ok, but [1, 3, 5] <-> [1, 3, 5] would fail. This would be impractical to implement and is not supported. It's the equivalent of requiring that a username not repeat a letter - "burt" would be ok but "burtbeckwith" would fail.

If you want to have unique elements in a collection, just change it from a List to a Set. You don't even need a constraint:

```
class Test {
   Set<BigDecimal> values
}
```

Comment: Burt, I would like the collection of values to be ordered, which is why a Set will not work.  I suppose the SortedSet would be the solution.